# What does the below code returns in jquery?

Tags: jquery, textbox

```
$("#para").text('')
.append($("input.selected").map(function() {
return $(this).val() || null;
}).get().join("<br/> "));
```

what is the purpose of  `$(this).val() || null;` here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`val()` returns the value of an input as a string. An empty string is a falsy value in JS, what that means is that if the string is empty then it will evaluate as false. The OR short-circuit operator `||` evaluates the code after it if the previous condition is false. So what that code is doing is returning `null` if the value is empty.

Answer (score 2):

[$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)... maps the value of input.selected to an array.. and `join` joins them with `<br>`.

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

so your code appends the value if exist or NULL of `input` with a class `selected` to your element with id `para`

**example..**

```
<div id="para"></div>

<input class="selected" value="test"/>
<input class="selected" value="test2"/>
 <input class="selected" value=""/>  // || NULL works here so returns null
```

the above function will append this

```
test <br> test2
```

to `#para`

**final result**

```
<div id="para">test <br> test2</div>  //result is the same
```